# Remove all Row Elements in JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this issue where I can't delete all of my added row data in just one click, I tried `$("#row").remove();` but it seems it removed one by one , I just want to remove all items added and uncheck all checkbox in the table when clicking removed. Did I miss something on my code?

```js
$("#allcb").change(function() {
  $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
    "checked",
    $(this).prop("checked")
  );
});


$(document).on("click", "#remove_all", function() {

  var $checkbox = $(`input[type='checkbox']`);
  $("#row").remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
});




$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity_input", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
  price_value = $(".price_value", $row).html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row", $row).text(total_value);
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var checkboxName = $row.data('for');
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);
  
  $row.remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
  $checkbox.get(0).hasCovered = false;
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_data").click(function() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var message = "Values                 Description\n";

    var checkBoxes = grid.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
    var str = ''

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb" &&
        !checkBoxes[i].hasCovered
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div id ="row" class="row" data-for="' + checkBoxes[i].id + '"><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class = "remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +

          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>&nbsp' +
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >total value is</span> ' +
          "</div><hr></div>";
        checkBoxes[i].hasCovered = true;
      }
    }
    $(".whole-div-class").append(str);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table border="1" id="Table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
          </th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
          </td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td> 25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
          </td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
          </td>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="add_data">Add datas</button>

    <button type="button" id="remove_all">Remove all</button>
    
    
    <!-- <div class="row whole-div-class"></div> -->
    <ul class="list-group mb-3 row whole-div-class"></ul>
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253592/discussion-on-question-by-marivic-valdehueza-remove-all-row-elements-in-jquery); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure what you intend to do but in js if you remove line 10 and replace line 11 with this it will work:

```js
var $checkbox = $(`input[type='checkbox']`);
```

Comment: I update the snippet above but when I clicked remove all it will remove the item one by one instead of removing it all

Comment: it erases everything for me

Comment: I tried it works but there's one last problem, is when I click button add data multiple times it will add data multiple times and the data will become redundant because it already exist in the list

Answer (score 0):

Use class instead of ID. Id should be unique. Secondly don't give row class to the ul. Because when you click remove all button, it is removing that ul and that's why the next time you are adding items, they are not showing. Lastly the logic for showing only unique item need to be updated. Here is the updated Code:-

```js
$("#allcb").change(function() {
      $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
        "checked",
        $(this).prop("checked")
      );
    });


$(document).on("click", "#remove_all", function() {
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type='checkbox']`);
  $(".row").remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
});




$(document).on("keyup", ".quantity_input", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var value_input = 0;
  var price_value = 0;
  var total_value = 0;

  value_input = $(".quantity_input", $row).val();
  price_value = $(".price_value", $row).html();
  total_value = parseInt(value_input) * parseInt(price_value);
  $(".total_value_row", $row).text(total_value);
});

$(document).on("click", ".remove_data", function() {
  var $row = $(this).closest('.row');
  var checkboxName = $(`.row[for="${$row.data('for')}"]`);
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type="checkbox"][name="${checkboxName}"]`);
  
  $row.remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#add_data").click(function() {
    var grid = document.getElementById("Table1");
    var message = "Values                 Description\n";
    var addedCheckboxes = $(".whole-div-class .row");

    var checkBoxes = $("input");
    var str = '';

    addedCheckboxes.map((i, addedCheckbox) => {
        checkBoxes = checkBoxes.filter((j, checkbox) => {
            return $(addedCheckbox).data('for') != $(checkbox).prop("name");
        });
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
      if (
        checkBoxes[i].checked &&
        checkBoxes[i].name !== "allcb"
      ) {
        var row = checkBoxes[i].parentNode.parentNode;
        str +=
          '<div id ="row" class="row" data-for="' + checkBoxes[i].id + '"><div class="col-md-8"><p class="me-3"> ' +
          '<a href="#" class="text-body">' +
          '<button type="button" class = "remove_data" id="remove_data">Remove item</button></a>&nbsp' +

          '<span>Quantity</span>&nbsp' +
          row.cells[2].innerHTML +
          "</a></p> " +
          '<span class="me-1">Price </span>&nbsp' +
          '<span class="me-1 price_value">' +
          row.cells[1].innerHTML +
          "</span>&nbsp" +
          '<input type="number" id="quantity_input" class="form-control form-control-sm w-px-75 quantity_input" value="1" min="1" max="5"/>&nbsp' +
          '<span class= "total_value_row" >total value is</span> ' +
          "</div><hr></div>";
      }
    }
    $(".whole-div-class").append(str);

  });
});



$("#allcb").change(function() {
   $('tbody tr td input[type="checkbox"]').prop(
       "checked",
       $(this).prop("checked")
    );
});

$(document).on("click", "#remove_all", function() {
  var $checkbox = $(`input[type='checkbox']`);
  $(".row").remove();
  $checkbox.prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" id="Table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="allcb" name="allcb" />
          </th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <td>Quantity</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb1" name="cb1" />
          </td>
          <td>200</td>
          <td> 25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb2" name="cb2" />
          </td>
          <td>300</td>
          <td>30</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb3" name="cb3" />
          </td>
          <td>400</td>
          <td>50</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button type="button" id="add_data">Add datas</button>

    <button type="button" id="remove_all">Remove all</button>
    <ul class="list-group mb-3 whole-div-class"></ul>
```